# What happens if i use more events in a single form validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
<body>
        <form id="register">
            First Name: <input type="text" id="abc" name="Firstname" size="50" onkeypress="return AvoidSpace(event)"><br><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" id="def" name="Lastname" size="50" onkeypress="return AvoidSpace(event)"><br><br>
            Address: <input type="text" id="ghi" name="Address" size="52"><br><br>
            City: <input type="text" id="jkl" name="City" size="56" onkeypress="return NumChar(event)"><br><br>
            State: <input type="text" id="mno" name="State" size="55" onkeypress="return NumChar(event)"><br><br>
            Pincode: <input type="text" id="pqr" name="Zipcode" maxlength="6" onkeypress="return ExceptNumber(event)"><br><br>
            Contact No: +91- <input type="text" id="stu" name="Phoneno" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return ExceptNumber(event)"><br><br>
            Email Id: <input type="email" id="vwx" name="Email" size="50" required><br><br>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="subFun()">
            <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="clearFunction()">
        </form>
</body>
```

I came to know that, if we use more events in the form validation, the form loading & submission will be time taking more time and also, based on the above program, input tag will be waiting unless and until the event has to be fired. Bit confused with this topic. What Happens actually if i use more events in a form. Is it the right way to use the events continuously???

Comment: I don't think this will add *time delay* that would be noticed. And its not wrong to use events to validate. Also I would suggest to use `keydown` instead of `keypress`

Comment: Following is a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/935L9bdz/) that depicts events on input. You can add validation code and test it